# Bar chart failing to render (Error in : First argument, `data`, must be a data frame or shared data. [No stack trace available])

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have the following data:

```
> data
creadate     employee  
2020-01-11        A A
2020-01-11        A A
2020-01-11        A A   
2020-01-12        A B 
2020-01-12        A B      
2020-01-12        A C      
2020-01-13        A C      
2020-01-14        A C      
2020-01-14        A D      
2020-01-15        A D
```

The objective is to build a shiny app containing a plotly graph. First, I want to transform the data and I add another column that counts the number of occurrences for each time frame(week, day, and date)-employee combination. E.g. the normal code for the week would be:

```
data %>% 
  count(Week = week(creadate), employee)
```

Now, I want to give the user the possibility to choose between the three choices. I write the following full code (see #2 specifically)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(plotly)

data <- read.csv("Desktop/adf.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4, 
           selectInput("timeFrame", "Select time frame", c("month", "week", "day"), multiple = TRUE), 
           dateRangeInput("date", "Select date", start  = "2020-01-01"),
    column(8, 
           plotlyOutput("errorTable")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {  
  
  #create a reactive object with a NULL starting value
  listofrows <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
  
  #observe the changes in inputs and update the reactive object 
  observeEvent(c(input$timeFrame, input$date), {
    
    listofrows$data <-  data %>% 
      subset(data, creadate >= input$date[1] & creadate <= input$date[2]) %>% # 1------------------------
      count(input$timeFrame[1] = input$timeFrame[1](creadate), employee) # 2-----------------------------
      

  }, ignoreInit = T,ignoreNULL = TRUE)
   
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(new_data,
      x = ~ input$timeFrame[1], 
      y = ~ n, 
      color = ~ employee, 
      frame = ~ input$timeFrame[1], 
      type = 'scatter',
      mode = 'markers'
    )
  }
  ) 
 }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, this code does not work. It tells:

````
Error in : First argument, `data`, must be a data frame or shared data.
  [No stack trace available]```
Do you have any idea?
````

Comment: What do you mean by “does not work”? Please be specific.

Comment: @KonradRudolph added the warning message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems.

The first is with the `subset` call, as indicated by the warning: you are passing `data` *twice* — once via the first explicit argument, and once since you’re using `subset` on the right-hand side of a pipe; the code

```r
data %>% 
  subset(data, creadate >= input$date[1] & creadate <= input$date[2]) …
```

is the same as

```r
subset(data, data, creadate >= input$date[1] & creadate <= input$date[2]) …
```

To fix this, remove the `data` argument. Furthermore, since you’re using the tidyverse, I recommend sticking to it, rather than mixing it with base functions; in other words, use `filter` instead of `subset`. Besides consistency, the `filter` function is also more robust in the face of errors and has better error messages than `subset`.

the second problem is your `count` function call — it’s not entirely clear what you’re attempting to do here. Consult [the documentation of the `count` function](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/count.html) to ensure you’re using it correctly.

---

There are more issues. For example, your plotting code uses a `new_data` variable that’s never defined. You probably want to use `listofrows$data` here. The arguments to `plot_ly` are also wrong: you can’t pass variables as formulas, you need to quote them properly (e.g. via `formula(paste('~', input$timeFrame[1]))`).

Comment: I already figured out the ```subset``` issue, and put the ```filter``` function. I also updated the title of the question. thanks anyways